# plasmapy - no installation candidate

Tags: drivers, software-installation, python3

I type this command to install the plasmapy module, but I just get:

```
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I've searched and tried to install python-dev in different ways
but when I try to install plasmapy module, I get the same error

I read all the relevant posts I could find here but I haven't found a solution that helped me yet.

Comment: Hello nafiseh sadat , and welcome to Ask Ubuntu. In order to increase that chances that somebody gives a good answer to your question, the first thing to do is ask a question; you should edit your post and actually include a question. You should also clarify the context: who gives that error message? When does it give that error message? What are you doing in order to make that error message appear? Is the error message unexpected? If so, what were you expecting to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PlasmaPy required Python 3.6+ package, check this [docs_plasmapy](http://docs.plasmapy.org/en/stable/index.html)

after Python 3.6+ installed,
run package using :

```
pip install
```

or

```
python setup.py install
```

**UPDATE ANSWERED**

to get requirement package use:

```
pip3 install plasmapy
```

run package using :

```
pip3 install .
```

or

```
python3 setup.py install
```

i hope this helps

Comment: sorry but i used all of these pip install.sudo pip install.python setup.py install and so on...

Comment: @nafisehsadat tell me sir, how you do installation that sir?

Comment: pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
pip install --upgrade setuptools

Comment: I exited from terminal now

Comment: i forgot to save command for this nesessery

Comment: @nafisehsadat please check my update answered